# Using schema.org/Product image on a non image element

Tags: seo, prestashop, product, schema.org, microdata

I am editing a Prestashop installation and have a slightly odd situation. In PS when you add a colour attribute to a product it shows an `<a>` tag with a background colour to show the colour choices. In the shop I am building for an art supplier, we are having one product per colour of paint so there is no need for this however some products will have an image of the texture and others will have a photograph showing the texture as not all of them will be a solid block of colour.

The whole scenario is a little more complex than above however my question is can you use the schema.org/Product image attributes on a tag which is empty but has a background colour?

The resulting code would be something like this wrapped in `<div class="product-container" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">`:

```
<a href="link-to-product" itemprop="image" style="background-color:#FF0000; width: 25px; height:25px;"></a>
```

I don't think it would be wise to delve into rewriting how Prestashop deals with Product Attributes for colours and other options because that would involve a certain kind of hell from what I have seen. The alternative is to leave the schema attributes out for those that don't have images but I would like to get it in there if possible. For those that don't know Prestashop, when you set product attributes you can choose a hexcode colour and an optional image file. If the image is not present then only the colour will show.

Comment: Could you include example code how this would look like?

Comment: @unor I've edited the question to include a basic code sample. I have lots of other elements and product schema attributes on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `itemprop` attribute for an `a` element, the property value will be the URL specified in the `href` attribute, not the content of the `a` element.

So in your example, the `image` property has the value `link-to-product` (which will be interpreted as URL):

```
schema:Product → schema:image → <link-to-product>
```

This is likely not what you want to say.

I did not understand exactly what you want to achieve, but if you do have an actual image that you want to provide as value for the `image` property, but you don’t want to use an `img` or `a` element, you could use a `link` element:

```html
<div class="product-container" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <link href="product-image.png" itemprop="image"/>
</div>
```

Comment: In all honesty I think I am going to have to negotiate a way around it with the client to make sure each product has an image even if its just a solid colour. I'm trying to work within the realms of Prestashop which allows you to have a background colour on an element but seeing as this is going to cause more problems from a coding point of view I think making each product have an image is the best way forward. Its good to know that it doesn't have to be an img tag though. I might try and find a work around for the link tag if needed. Thanks for taking time to answer

Comment: @James: If it’s a "solid" color, you could use the [`color` property](http://schema.org/color) instead. Similar to the `link`, it can also be specified in a hidden way with `meta`: `<meta itemprop="color" content="Red"/>`. So you can keep the PS markup (without applying Microdata) and add these `link`/`meta` elements in addition. -- That being said, actual content should not be conveyed with CSS (users without CSS support would not be able to learn which color/texture your products have).

Comment: Good call! I didn't even think about that the color property. Just having a look at the docs, it says use Text for the value. Guessing that means no hex codes? Being an art shop it has some very inventive colour names so may or may not work.

Comment: @James: I think it’s allowed to specify hex values (they *are* text); it’s just the question how useful hex values are for consumers of the data.

Comment: True, hex is text I suppose. Well I shall put some in and see how it goes. The site is still in development so we have a bit of time to experiment. Thanks for your help